# Django ORM compound filter with variables

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I'm by no means a Django expert, and need some guidance on a problem.

For background, I have a older .NET project that I've been tasked to turn into Django project. The project gets a full list of objects and then runs a large set of user set filters to end up with the desired set of objects.

*One of the filters in .NET might be like so ...*

```
matched.RemoveAll(x => ((x.annualIncome / 12) - x.payment) < monthlyIncome);
```

I'm trying to figure out how I would do this with the django ORM.  I'm kind off stuck on this.

*In a pseudo-code django ORM version (yes, this will not work):*

```
matched.exclude(((annualIncome /12)-payment)__gt = monthlyIncome)
```

There are 30+ filters before this one so I can't re-do them all in a different manner.  I can obviously go through each object and filter but I decided to ask first.

I'm open to solutions here or friendly "RTFM, this pages answers it."

Thanks in advance, and mods please edit with a better title as my brain is now officially fried from 3 days coding with the Flu.

Comment: I could help you, but I do not speak .NET and from you text I can't figure out which parts of the pseudo code are actually model fields and which are just variables... Can I assume that `annualIncome` and `payment` are int/float variables and `monthlyIncome` is the DB field to filter upon?

Comment: annualIncome and payment are model fields and monthlyIncome is a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case welcome to the magical world of Django ORM (and not in a bad sense, it's actually pretty reasonable most of the time :).

```
from django.db.models import F, Case

# Your stuff
matches.annotate(
    req=Case(default=(F('annualIncome') / 12) - F('payment'))
).exclude(req__gt=monthlyIncome)
```

Because you can't query directly in that kind of a calculation, then the `F` object tells ORM that this should come from the database, go and get it.
Untested (due to lack of similar case in my projects), but if problems arise, do let me know.

PS. You can change the `req` name to whatever you like.

EDIT:
Wow, this is awkward. You can just do it without the `Case` as well.

```
matches.annotate(req=(F('annualIncome') / 12) - F('payment')).exclude(req__gt=monthlyIncome)
```

Comment: I totally get it.  Thanks again @makaveli - this is exactly what I was looking for.